# SD-App on OSX (or alternative distributed bug tracker with sync to GitHub)

Tags: git, github, tracker

I have been working trying to install via CPAN and GIT SD ( http://syncwith.us/sd/ ) on an Intel MBP on OSX. So far it has been a unsuccessful process.

My question is has anyone else installed SD under OSX and if so if you have any links to guidance that would be really helpful, so far JFGI has not worked for me.

Alternatively, I would be intereste to know what distributed bug/issue trackers people are actually using in anger. I have looked around and there are several projects that much like SD seem to have stalled.

SD appealled as it claims to sync with Github's issue tracker. So would be ideal for me as the main project I want to work offline with is hosted there and the current bugs are there already.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Lance

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was the way I was accessing CPAN (I think).
I found I could install success fully if I entered the CPAN shell using the following command:

sudo perl -MCPAN -e "shell"

Then typing:

install App:SD

I followed all the dependencies and SD installed OK. I am now happily syncing bug lists with GitHub for update offline, brilliant!

Hopefully, this answer will help others.

Lance